# CursorLoader as ContentProvider changes observer

Tags: android

I have a list with 1000 items. After one item was updated I would like my view reflects the changes in this item immediately. So does the CursorLoader know exactly what item was changed? I wouldn't like it retrieves all 1000 items again from ContentProvider when one item's update was received.

Comment: you can refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517920/how-do-cursorloader-automatically-updates-the-view-even-if-the-app-is-inactive