# How to use CursorAdapter with CursorLoader and LoaderManager to update ListView when Database Updates

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, android-sqlite

Right now I am using CursorAdapter to populate my listview by getting the cursor data from my sqlite database. I am able to load the listview. I am able to add, edit or delete an item which also reflects in database. But when I do so the listview does not reflect it in the UI until i reload the app or activity.

I surfed a lot and found that I can achieve what I want using CursorLoader and LoaderManager. But I don't know that how to use them with CursorAdapter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517920/how-do-cursorloader-automatically-updates-the-view-even-if-the-app-is-inactive

Comment: just use adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya The main thing is to requery the database and set the cursor with the updated data.

Comment: ok sorry for my suggestion then its not good way to refresh adapter

Comment: `CursorLoader` delivers `Cursor` which you can use by simply calling `adapter.swapCursor(data)`, more https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example

Comment: @pskink then does i require to use CursorAdapter or just CursorLoader will work?

Comment: both: loader loads `Cursor` in the background and adapter uses it to show it in your list view, all what you need is a "smart" content provider like this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.java, notice `setNotificationUri` and `notifyChange` methods