# How make a synchronization with ListView from a dialog window?

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog, synchronization

**Here's my code-**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {

        builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert1 = builder1.create();
        layoutInflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        layout1 = layoutInflater1.inflate(R.layout.alert_one, null);
        alert1.setView(layout1);

        buttonAlert_oneDelete = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneDelete);
        buttonAlert_oneUpdate = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneUpdate);
        buttonAlert_oneCancel = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert_oneCancel);

        buttonAlert_oneDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                funDelete(id);
                simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                alert1.cancel();
            }
        });

        buttonAlert_oneCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                alert1.cancel();
            }
        });     
        alert1.show();
    }
});
```

**funDelete** method

```
private void funDelete(long id) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
  db.delete(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME,AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id), null); 
}
```

Hi! A method **notifyDataSetChanged()** does not **ListView** at once after deleting the line from database. How this make? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you explain your question a little more..

Comment: show your function delete and initializing statement of adapter..

Comment: I guess this is because deleting from the database is an async function. If you call `notifyDataSetChanged` after calling `funDelete`, the async function may not have completed by that time. Call `notifyDataSetChanged` inside `funDelete` where you can be sure that the delete operation has completed.

Comment: Post your `funDelete(id)` method code. and where you get `id` ?

Comment: When I press a button "DELETE" in this dialog window the ListView must changes now

Comment: `private void funDelete(long id) {
  db = abcDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  db.delete(AbcDbContract.TableWords.TABLE_NAME, AbcDbContract.TableWords.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id), null);
 }`

Comment: Just edit your question and add this code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Adapter` doesn't know about your Database Table. Adapter only know about its data source which is `List` or `Array`. So in this scenario you have to reload data from Database and update Adapter.

```
 buttonAlert_oneDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    funDelete(id);
    // reload datafrom Database
    // update datasource of the  simpleCursorAdapter 
    simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    alert1.cancel();
   }
});
```

If you use [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) then you don't need to query manually. [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) automatically registers a `ContentObserver` to trigger a reload when data changes. You just have to call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` after any update/insert/delete operation.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529866/1292557) answer how to implement it .

Comment: Abu Yousuf thank you very much! I make this problem. You can look [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784387/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-listview-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment1232161_784387)

Comment: Don't know russian language :p